# Compiled script code is too long: Nightmare

Tags: pine-script

I think many many many developers are hitting this problem all the time, our scripts are complex and all-in-one. There's no real solution from TradingView's team. I'm really not sure how da heck optimize more. Any help here?

Examples:

```
if hasToLongAllStableTriggers_highestEma
    b_long_isBullishHighestEmaBounce := true
```

This generates 36 lines of code! Non-sense...

```
f_create_strategy(trigger, long_input, SL_long, id_str) =>
    if isActivateLongs and window() // Date time
        [b_close, long_comment] = f_triggerOption(long_input)
        [SL_b_close, SL_comment] = f_triggerOption(SL_long)
        SL_manipulation = rel_isYellowCross or A_isYellowCross
        
        if trigger and long_comment != None and b_close == false and SL_b_close == false and SL_manipulation == false
            strategy.entry(long=strategy.long, limit=close, id=id_str, comment=id_str)
        // Close
        if b_close
            strategy.close(id=id_str, comment=long_comment)
        // Stop Loss
        if SL_b_close
            strategy.close(id=id_str, comment=SL_comment)
        // Global manipulation
        if SL_by_manipulation and SL_manipulation
            strategy.close(id=id_str, comment="Manipulation Signal")
        //
        // Global - Take Profits - LONG
        //
        if enableTpForLongs and enableStopLossForLongs
            strategy.exit("TP/SL", id_str, limit=longTpPrice, stop=longStopPrice)
        
        else if enableTpForLongs
            strategy.exit("TP", id_str, limit=longTpPrice)
        //
        // Global - Stop Loss - LONG
        //
        else if enableStopLossForLongs
            strategy.exit("SL", id_str, stop=longStopPrice)
    

f_find_back(trigger, trigger_to_search, min_back, max_back) =>
    found = false
    if trigger
        for i = min_back to max_back
            if trigger_to_search[i]
                found := true
                break
    found
//
// 
//
isBullishDivHigherEma_long_run = rel_higher_ema1_BullDiv and floor(rel_higher_ema1)[3] < floor(rel_higher_ema1) and rel_higher_ema1 > osLevel2
isBullishDivHigherEma_ema8_low = rel_higher_ema1_BullDiv and rel_ema8 <= slArea
//isBullishDivHigherEma = rel_higher_ema1_BullDiv and rel_higher_ema1 > rel_higher_ema1_Low_prev 

isBullishDivHigherEma = f_find_back(rel_higher_ema1_Low_prev < rel_higher_ema1_Low_prev[1], rel_higher_ema1_BullDiv, 1, 10)

b_long_isBullishDivHigherEma = input(group = id_isBullishDivHigherEma, defval=true, title=str_input_long)
//if hasToLongAllStableTriggers_higherEma
//    b_long_isBullishDivHigherEma := true
    
long_isBullishDivHigherEma = input(group = id_isBullishDivHigherEma, defval=TPLevelCrossUpEma1, title=str_input_closeby, type=input.string, options=[None, TPLevelCrossUpEma1])
SL_isBullishDivHigherEma = input(group = id_isBullishDivHigherEma, defval=None, title=str_input_sl, type=input.string, options=[None, TPLevelCrossUpEma1])
if b_long_isBullishDivHigherEma
    f_create_strategy(isBullishDivHigherEma, long_isBullishDivHigherEma, SL_isBullishDivHigherEma, id_isBullishDivHigherEma)
```

Generates more than 6464, at least, as the limit is 60k guessing the overflow is the amount for instance.

Thanks and bless you if you have an answer!

Comment: More info:
f_triggerOption are just a bunch of if-else if removing the content it's just 100~ lines of compiled code

removing individual sections of f_create_strategy doesn't remove much lines... however removing the WHOLE function content does!

I'm very confused with how pinescript does the branching and code generation in the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runaway backtesting inside of a function using a for-loop.

The solution is to remove the logic of f_find_back out of the function and you save thousands and thousands of generated nonsense code lines.

2 ways:

```
result := false
if condition
    // Option 1
    for i = 1 to 10
        if what_you_want_to_back_test[i]
            result := true
            break
    // Option 2 - Transform series[bool] to a sum integer      
    float f_counter = 0.0 
    for i = 1 to 10
        f_counter += what_you_want_to_back_test[i] ? 1 : 0
        
    result := f_counter > 0.0
```

**Both options consume too few generated lines of code. The biggest shame about pine script is that it's impossible to rely on any type of support, even if you pay money.**